# Вывод значений (Maple)

Tags: c, maple

В Maple есть программа, которая должна выводить все значения от 1 до n по формуле. Но программа выводит только последнее значение. Я уже пробовал делать всякие простейшие программки в maple и ни одна из них не выводит все значения цикла, а только последнее.
Знаю только, что если записать нужные значения для вывода через кому, то тогда норм выводит. Но это жутко неудобно и громоздко. Если кто знает, помогите, пожалуйста.

```
y1 := proc (n) 
local i, y, x; 
y[-1] := 0; 
y[0] := 1; 
for i from 1 to n do 
y[i] := y[i-1]+a(i)*x[i]*y[n-i]
y[i];
end do;
end proc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Недавно Сам столкнулся с данной проблемой, токо работаю я с маплетом и пример также покажу для маплета.
Для этого я использовал seq к примеру:

```
y1:=proc(n,x,a)
global y2:
local i, y1, y;

y1[-1] := 0; 
y1[0] := 1; 
for i from 1 to n do 
y1[i] := y1[i-1]+a(i)*x[i]*y1[n-i]:
y2:=<seq(y[i],i=1..n)> = <seq(y1[i],i=1..n)>:
end do;
return :
end:

["Выведим y:",
[MathMLViewer['Z_5_10'](100..250),Button("найти",Evaluate('Z_5_10'='
[y1(n,x,a), y2]
'))]],
```

Результат будет выводится в виде матрицы
Вывод будет типа

```
> y[1]=3.333
> y[2]=3.433
> y[3]=3.533
```

y[i]-это у нас символ (y[1],y[2] и так дальше), а y1[i]-это именно нужное Вам значение (3.333,3.433)
Эта матрица присваивается y2 которое мы и выводим